# 'unfortunately launcher has stopped' in screen resolution 240x240 of Android 4.2.2 Emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

In Android avd emulator,
When i generate the Android AVD of screen resolution 240x240 in Android 4.2.2,it can enter the main screen on booting.
But when i click "app list"[image: app list] to browser all apps,it show failure message "unfortunately launcher has stopped".
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think the minimum supported is 240x320, lower resolutions may behave oddly...

Comment: thank ur reply,but i must force to 240x240 resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android avd emulator,.

When You Open that avd you will this option.

[image]
 in that At Resolution First You need to Mention The Emulartor..

You can see [Managing Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)
or [Manage AVD in Cmd line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html)

But Right Now We have By Default Only One Device at AVD  which is low end its 240x320 We don't have less than that,. But If you design a app under this will support 240x240 But not less than that..

I think You are You are using.. android Build Tools IDE..

Insted Of That You need to Download `Eclipe J2EE` IDE Saperately and You can add Android SDK + ADT Plugin saperately Visit this for [Existing IDE](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

Why this Because Over here You can adjust according to your screen,..

and Regarding App launcher issue

That Problem with launcher.. to avoid that Design a new AVD

In that from the above Screen Short You have a Option called `Snapshort` click Enable on that Check Box...
so for first time it will be Slow.. But for Next time i will load Very fastly..
For first time wait for Launcher Responce.. Than next Time This will Not be a Issue..
If you Enable Snapshort..

Comment: Here I Updated my answer,. Please follow those instructions.. and don't forget to up-vote my answer and tick right.. I already up-voted your question